# Breaking huge data to show in multiple pages or list without scripts

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I'm looking for general idea about how can achieve the following functionality (look at Google page image) without any scripting language like Java Script. It's to reduce load on my web page that currently fetching all the data in single list.

[Google Page Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiWne.png)

Yes, I do want that navigation numbers below page to direct user to desired page but what I don't want is, those arrows on side and above loooooong written Google name so don't worry about that. I don't want any pre-written code, just an idea about how I can achieve that, is more than enough. I can come up with relevant code.

I'm working with PHP, MySQL, HTML and CSS.

Comment: search for "recordset paging in php and mysql"

Comment: Pretty on point term @RamRaider, that solved my confusion. Please write it again as answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: No matter how many words I use the succinct term above is not worthy of an answer- but thank you for the offer. Good luck with the sql/php coding ~ it's easy when you have seen an example or two

Comment: `without any scripting language like Java Script` `working with PHP` no client side scripting, but server side PHP, correct?

Comment: Yes sir, but I already found solution if you got better one please go ahead and tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RamRaider said in comments , this functionality is achieved by “Recordset paging”. It does not require any client side script and does the job efficiently. Read about it to see how it’s relevant to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done with adding a page parameter to URLs (?page=5), then using LIMIT in the SQL query to select only the relevant rows  for the given page..